A short story where all humans deliberately evacuate Earth to allow its ecology to recover
I don't even remember when I read this short story, except it was very long ago, nor whether I read it in French or English.
After my question on the last zoo on Earth was answered, Jason Patterson wrote a note about another story by Asimov, with the opposite philosophy. That story is "The Greatest Asset". I did find and read it.
But this reminded me of a third short story, opposite to the first one, not on a philosophical point of view, but rather on a "practical" one. Indeed, the subject was the evacuation of Earth by all humans. They had to leave for somewhere is space, anywhere but on Earth's surface. It might also be by Asimov, but maybe not.
The reason was not a recently occurred disaster, like nuclear war, or a collision with a asteroid.
It was a deliberate decision, considering the worsening of the ecology, which was severe but not yet irreversible, to allow Earth to recover its equilibrium. The last few sentences, IIRC, were the nostalgic thoughts of the last humans to leave Earth, sad to leave forever their planet, but wishing a full recovery to the remainder of the animals and plants.

Wormhole Magic by Marianne Plumridge is about a group on the Moon monitoring Earth after it was evacuated for exactly the reasons your describe. It ends: I raised my mug and toasted the Earth loitering in its usual position over the Moon horizon in the dining room window. “Merry Christmas, old girl. It seems that there’s hope for us yet.” It's from 2004.

Good attempt. But the last lines quoted by Ubik fit my memory much better. They coincide with the evacuation, while yours is about monitoring afterwards. But thanks anyway.

This also describes the premise of WALL-E.

@Fellmeister But one does not see it happen. In my book, which Ubik identified it as "The last Shuttle", the story is about the evacuation itself, not its aftermath.

Becky Chambers' Wayfarer series (which begins with The Long Way to a Small, Angry Planet) has this element too. Humanity left Earth when its ecosystem largely collapsed and rendered it generally uninhabitable by humans; humanity is now spread around, with the largest factions being Martians (Mars isn't terraformed, but the colonies there are extensive) and Exodans, who hail from the Exodus Fleet formed of the various ships that left Earth and eventually made first contact with extraterrestrial life.

@anaximander  It does not look like a short story ! Also it is long after the the evacuation, not just at that time.

This is indeed a story by Isaac Asimov, "The Last Shuttle", first published in 1981 and collected in The Winds of Change and Other Stories in 1983.
The last sentences are

Earth was returned to its wilderness and its wildlife by a humanity grateful to its mother planet and ready to retire it to the rest it deserved. It would remain forever as a monument to humanity’s origin.
    The last shuttle lifted through the wisps of the upper atmosphere and the Earth stretched below it and would now be shrinking as the shuttle receded.
    It had been solemnly agreed by the fifteen billion residents of space that human feet would never stand on it again.
    Earth was free! Free at last!

